# Combine Webforms to export multiple form results in a single CSV

Tags: views, webforms, importing-exporting, files

I need to be able to select multiple webforms and then be able to export all of their results in a single CSV download.

I am considering using this module ([Views data export](http://drupal.org/node/1820452)) but I'm not yet sure it will fit the task.

Any suggestions on the approach you would take would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
I approached this using the 'Webform Mysql Views' module but the process is incredibly time consuming as each Webform needs to have a view created for its submissions. These fields then need to be associated in the Webform Submissions view and duplicate fields need to be merged.

Answer (score 1):

Webform 4.x is integrated out of the box with views on drupal 7.

1. Upgrade to last webform 7.x-4.x release.[image: version]
2. Create a view: webform submissions [image]
3. Select each field: webform submission data:Value and your webform node to extract the fields [image: field configuration]

To download all results the best option is [Views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export), you should configure it to use batch for better performance.