# How do I export webform data input to CSV / XLS?

Tags: 8, webforms

I have a simple one-page form (name, address, etc). I would like to export the data of the submitted webform by the user into CSV / XLS files.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module you can download submission's results in  csv/xls files.
if you want to do that go to:

content => select the webform you need to export => click on the result tab => finaly click on the download button.

If you need more flexibility like exporting multiple webforms 
Which fulfill certain conditions.

Take a look at the [Forena Reports](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module and this [post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/229425/how-to-build-my-sql-statement-to-export-all-webform-submissions-using-forena/229523#229523) in which a detailed exemple is given by a co-maintainer of the forena module.

Comment: Hm, just stumbled upon this answer, merci for the link to the post in which I included that example!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add information to HusterFrancis posts. People who who feel limited by the core contact functionality in Drupal 8. [There is a beta version webform 8.x.](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/releases/8.x-5.0-beta7)

Works very well. It does everything from scratch. (Export of data input, conditional rules, e-mail handling, etc)